# Real time response from one client to another

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm currently developing a website and I would like to do the following:

While two users are logged in on their user accounts, if one of them has pressed a certain button (let's say "Alert your friend") a message should be displayed to the second user (e.g. "Your friend has just alerted you!") - those are just examples, the basic thing I want to be done is real-time response from one client to another based on certain actions.

I've asked someone before wasting any valuable time of people in here and told me I might get this done with AJAX.

My question is: could it work? May someone give me a point of start or any other small piece of information that would help me get on the right road?

Thank you a million, I'll be really grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [ajax wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to get familiar with it.

(I am not expert in Ajax, so details could be wrong)

Basically, you should add some javascript code which periodically makes an asynchronoous [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to query your web server. You need some Javascript [timer](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Answer (score 0):

If this a website that your are developing and to me it seems to me to be like the facebook poke feature, which from what i understand above.
I would do the following

I dont think this feature will be solved just by AJAX? 
Since it is a web page that is served out of a server you will need a backend system to make the pokes flow across to the other user. You can use a DB that will store the alerts and when page loads read from the DB.
You can also use WCF to enable this and then use AJAX to make the calls behind the scene.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the right direction.

However, considering "real-time" and server stress. An advanced tech should be used for production.

Like Ajax Long-polling [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

or WebSocket http://websocket.org/

Your requirement can be treated as a chatroom. "Alert your friend" is the same as "Private message to a person in chatroom". There are many chatroom examples you can refer to.